# Where is snappy installed via homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I've installed snappy (I think) with `brew install snappy`.

And  `brew info snappy` gives

```
snappy: stable 1.1.7 (bottled), HEAD
Compression/decompression library aiming for high speed
https://google.github.io/snappy/
/usr/local/Cellar/snappy/1.1.7_1 (18 files, 118KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-04-04 at 19:44:10
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/snappy.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔, pkg-config ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

Yet there is no `snappy` in `/usr/local/bin`. Where is it?

Comment: Seems like a library for use in code, does it even have an executable? In any case, if you are able to run `snappy` as a command then you could do a `which snappy` to locate it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ah! Need to run `brew install snzip` to create a command line wrapper to the snappy library.

Can run `snzip -k FILE` to compress a file and keep it. `snzip -d FILE.sz` to decompress.